# NER model training with IOB encoding fails (Stanford CoreNLP)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp

I am trying to train a NER model for Stanford CoreNLP. But as soon as the 8th or 9th iteration of the training process is reached, it stops and nothing else is happening.

The corpus is annotated with IOB/BIO encoding like this:

```
How O
to  O
play    O
a   O
video   O
in  O
Java    B-Fram
Swing   I-Fram
?   O
```

My properties file:

```
trainFile = C:\\Data\\corpora\\train\\train.tsv
serializeTo = C:\\Data\\ner-model.ser.gz

map = word=0,answer=1

useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
useDisjunctive=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
maxLeft=2
maxRight=2
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
useGazettes=true
sloppyGazette=true
gazette=C:\\Data\\gazetteers\\gaz1.txt,C:\\Data\\gazetteers\\gaz2.txt
entitySubclassification=bio
```

The content of my Gazetteers:

```
Fram LiteDB
Fram RavenDB
Fram MongoDB
Fram Cassandra
Fram Couchbase
...
```

The command for the training process:

`java -mx8g -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop C:\\Data\\ner.prop -readerAndWriter edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.CoNLLDocumentReaderAndWriter`

Why is the training process suddenly stopping? Has this something to do with incorrect properties? Or does the gazetteers have to have the same labels as the annotated corpus?

At the end I want the entities to be tagged with just "Fram" instead of "B-Fram" or "I-Fram". How is that possible?

Thank you in advance.